# Error in creating new project in phonegap?

Tags: phonegap-build

Whenever I want to create new project in phone gap. I have got the following error.
[Error which i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2Qm8.png)

Comment: When are you getting the event error and what is the complete error?

Comment: whenever i create new project in phonegap software. I have got this error. This is the complete error which i have sent as a image

Comment: What version of cordova is being installed? Can you tell me what version of Nodejs are you using?

Comment: Actually i am new to this. Do i require nodejs in windows? and from where i suppose to download corodova?

Comment: Can you put the command `node -v` and provide the version. Second, inside the project where you are creating a new project there must be a package.json. Can you copy paste the package.json in the question. Also please update/edit the question with what steps you are following to create a project. I am unable to replicate the issue.

Comment: My version is v6.10.3 
i have installed cordova by using the following command:
npm install -g cordova.
New project is not created so there is no json package available there

Comment: npm install -g cordova is only going to install cordova for your system. Please follow steps to use cordova api in your projects using the getting started. `https://cordova.apache.org/#getstarted`. If you are not sure how to get started I recommend you to use Ionic 1 or 2 which uses angularjs/angular but will get the bootstrap done for you correctly. Remember if you need android build you have to install Android SDK also from Android site.

Comment: This is not a PhoneGap Build question. Please change your tags to Phonegap.

Comment: You do not need Ionic. Please refer to the full Phoengap docs, here: http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/1-install-phonegap/desktop/

Answer (score 0):

First of all install the node from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

and after that install the phonegap

```
npm install -g phonegap
```

and then create the new project.
Syntax is `phonegap create foldername packagename applicationname`

For Example,

```
phonegap create demo com.demo demo
```

Its working properly.